# How to SSH in to different containers in Multi Container Azure App Service

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service, linux-containers

I want to SSH to my containers created in an Azure App Service. These are Linux based containers and used Docker Compose to deploy these to Azure App Service.

I have followed the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container#enable-ssh) to enable SSH. For one of the container (Container A) I am able to SSH (exposed port 2222, 80 for this). But I would like to SSH to other containers (Container B) too. I have exposed another port 2223 for Container B and followed the same steps in that document. When I try to access them using the command *ssh root@172.xx.x.x -p 2223*, I get the error Connection Refused. But the command *ssh root@172.xx.x.x -p 2222* works for the Container A and I am able to see the Dotnet process running for the API in that Container A when I run the Top command

Comment: As a general rule, you don’t ssh into containers.  A container usually runs a single process and that single process is almost never an ssh daemon.  Think of a container as a wrapper around a process and not a managed VM.

Comment: "its not connecting" This is pretty vague. Please [edit] your question to describe specifically what happens. Do you get an error message? What does it say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further research, I found out that we cannot SSH to multi container. Currently Azure supports SSH to public facing container only. Based on this [link](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/aae6e6dd-c925-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0f1c) its planned by Azure App Service team!

Answer (score 4):

This is still not supported in 2020. For further info you can also check with GitHub repo for App Service.

https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs

For SSH in multicontainer app service, you can't select a specific container to SSH to. It's not possible as of today. Always the front-facing container is picked up for SSH which is mostly at 80 port also if not then the first container in yaml file.

https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/how_multicontainer_webapp_determine_web_container.md

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/34743265-support-ssh-to-specific-container-in-multi-contain

This is the thread from product owner in late 2018. Seems like they still haven't approved that functionality.

[How to SSH in to different containers in Multi Container Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57676203/how-to-ssh-in-to-different-containers-in-multi-container-azure-app-service)