# Does Azure Web App for containers support ssh access when running a multi-container app?

Tags: azure, docker, ssh, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service

I'm running an Azure Web app (containers) with custom container images.  I've followed the steps to enable ssh into a container image and it works great when I'm only running a single container.  But when I run the app as a multi-container app (with docker-compose file) with more than one container image I get the error below.  For additional context this is a small python web app that using nginx and redis hence the need for more than one container.  Only one of my custom images has ssh enabled and running and exposing port 2222.

Is this even possible?  If not then I'm not sure how feasible it is to run a web app multi-container if I have no way to access a container for support purposes.

```
az webapp remote-connection create -g GROUPNAME -n APPNAME -p 2222 --verbose                 
Configured default 'GROUPNAME' for arg resource_group_name
remote-connection is deprecated and moving to cli-core, use `webapp create-remote-connection`
Port 2222 is open
Creating a socket on port: 2222
Setting socket options
Binding to socket on local address and port
Finished initialization
Status response message: FAILURE:2222:Unable to connect to WebApp
WARNING - Remote debugging may not be setup properly. Reponse content: FAILURE:2222:Unable to connect to WebApp
SSH is available { username: root, password: Docker! }
Start your favorite client and connect to port 2222
```

I also tried the create-remote-connection command but got similar results.

`az webapp create-remote-connection -n APPNAME -g GROUPNAME --verbose &`

Error I receive is:

```
Auto-selecting port: 52661
Finished initialization
Status response message: FAILURE:2222:Unable to connect to WebApp
WARNING - Remote debugging may not be setup properly. Reponse content: FAILURE:2222:Unable to connect to WebApp
Connection is not ready yet, please wait
.
Status response message: FAILURE:2222:Unable to connect to WebApp
WARNING - Remote debugging may not be setup properly. Reponse content: FAILURE:2222:Unable to connect to WebApp
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its not supported :(

see...

[How to SSH in to different containers in Multi Container Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57676203/how-to-ssh-in-to-different-containers-in-multi-container-azure-app-service)

and...

[Support SSH to specific container in multi-container setup](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/34743265-support-ssh-to-specific-container-in-multi-contain)