# Open ssh port on Azure multi-container app

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to ssh into my multi-container web app hosted on Azure App Service.

I followed the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-container-app#prerequisites) on their documentation page and was able to get the app to start.
[image: working web app]

When I try to SSH into the web app I get

> SSH CONNECTION CLOSE - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED xxxx.xx.x.x:2222

I researched and made some modifications to my SSHD_CONFIG according to the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#enable-ssh). My SSHD_CONFIG is like this:

```
Port                2222
ListenAddress       0.0.0.0
LoginGraceTime      180
X11Forwarding       yes
Ciphers             aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc
MACs                hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
StrictModes         yes
SyslogFacility      DAEMON
PrintMotd           no
IgnoreRhosts        no
```

My edited Dockerfile is:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

# install the PHP extensions we need
RUN set -ex; \
    \
    savedAptMark="$(apt-mark showmanual)"; \
    \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    ; \
    \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr; \
    docker-php-ext-install gd mysqli opcache; \
    \
# reset apt-mark's "manual" list so that "purge --auto-remove" will remove all build dependencies
    apt-mark auto '.*' > /dev/null; \
    apt-mark manual $savedAptMark; \
    ldd "$(php -r 'echo ini_get("extension_dir");')"/*.so \
        | awk '/=>/ { print $3 }' \
        | sort -u \
        | xargs -r dpkg-query -S \
        | cut -d: -f1 \
        | sort -u \
        | xargs -rt apt-mark manual; \
    \
    apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#install redis php extension
ENV PHPREDIS_VERSION=4.0.2

RUN docker-php-source extract \
  && curl -L -o /tmp/redis.tar.gz https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/$PHPREDIS_VERSION.tar.gz \
  && tar xfz /tmp/redis.tar.gz \
  && rm -r /tmp/redis.tar.gz \
  && mv phpredis-$PHPREDIS_VERSION /usr/src/php/ext/redis \
  && docker-php-ext-install redis \
  && docker-php-source delete

# set recommended PHP.ini settings
# see https://secure.php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php
RUN { \
        echo 'opcache.memory_consumption=128'; \
        echo 'opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8'; \
        echo 'opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000'; \
        echo 'opcache.revalidate_freq=2'; \
        echo 'opcache.fast_shutdown=1'; \
        echo 'opcache.enable_cli=1'; \
    } > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache-recommended.ini

RUN a2enmod rewrite expires

VOLUME /var/www/html

ENV WORDPRESS_VERSION 4.9.6
ENV WORDPRESS_SHA1 6992f19163e21720b5693bed71ffe1ab17a4533a

RUN set -ex; \
    curl -o wordpress.tar.gz -fSL "https://wordpress.org/wordpress-${WORDPRESS_VERSION}.tar.gz"; \
    echo "$WORDPRESS_SHA1 *wordpress.tar.gz" | sha1sum -c -; \
# upstream tarballs include ./wordpress/ so this gives us /usr/src/wordpress
    tar -xzf wordpress.tar.gz -C /usr/src/; \
    rm wordpress.tar.gz; \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/src/wordpress

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/

ENV SSH_PASSWD "root:Docker!"

RUN apt-get update \
        && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends dialog \
        && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssh-server \
    && echo "$SSH_PASSWD" | chpasswd

COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/

RUN mkdir -p /tmp
COPY ssh_setup.sh /tmp

RUN chmod +x /tmp/ssh_setup.sh


# Open port 2222 for SSH access
EXPOSE 80 2222

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

Then my docker logs is:

```
2022-02-22T06:30:33.008Z INFO  - Starting multi-container app..
2022-02-22T06:30:34.367Z INFO  - Pulling image: mysql:5.7
2022-02-22T06:30:35.504Z INFO  - 5.7 Pulling from library/mysql
2022-02-22T06:30:35.869Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Pulling fs layer
2022-02-22T06:30:35.878Z INFO  - d69aa66e4482 Pulling fs layer
2022-02-22T06:30:35.878Z INFO  - 3b19465b002b Pulling fs layer
2022-02-22T06:30:35.878Z INFO  - 7b0d0cfe99a1 Pulling fs layer
2022-02-22T06:30:35.878Z INFO  - 9ccd5a5c8987 Pulling fs layer
2022-02-22T06:30:35.878Z INFO  - 2dab00d7d232 Pulling fs layer
2022-02-22T06:30:35.878Z INFO  - 5d726bac08ea Pulling fs layer
2022-02-22T06:30:35.878Z INFO  - f2f4aec225fa Pulling fs layer
2022-02-22T06:30:35.878Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Pulling fs layer
2022-02-22T06:30:35.878Z INFO  - 96d7660d55cf Pulling fs layer
2022-02-22T06:30:35.878Z INFO  - c4976e34a8d2 Pulling fs layer
2022-02-22T06:30:36.315Z INFO  - 9ccd5a5c8987 Downloading 149B / 149B
2022-02-22T06:30:36.315Z INFO  - 9ccd5a5c8987 Verifying Checksum
2022-02-22T06:30:36.315Z INFO  - 9ccd5a5c8987 Download complete
2022-02-22T06:30:36.376Z INFO  - c4976e34a8d2 Downloading 121B / 121B
2022-02-22T06:30:36.376Z INFO  - d69aa66e4482 Downloading 1KB / 1KB
2022-02-22T06:30:36.377Z INFO  - 96d7660d55cf Downloading 4KB / 4KB
2022-02-22T06:30:36.377Z INFO  - 3b19465b002b Verifying Checksum
2022-02-22T06:30:36.377Z INFO  - 3b19465b002b Download complete
2022-02-22T06:30:36.378Z INFO  - c4976e34a8d2 Verifying Checksum
2022-02-22T06:30:36.378Z INFO  - c4976e34a8d2 Download complete
2022-02-22T06:30:36.378Z INFO  - d69aa66e4482 Verifying Checksum
2022-02-22T06:30:36.396Z INFO  - d69aa66e4482 Download complete
2022-02-22T06:30:36.396Z INFO  - 96d7660d55cf Verifying Checksum
2022-02-22T06:30:36.396Z INFO  - 96d7660d55cf Download complete
2022-02-22T06:30:36.396Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Downloading 518KB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:36.417Z INFO  - f2f4aec225fa Downloading 252B / 252B
2022-02-22T06:30:36.417Z INFO  - f2f4aec225fa Verifying Checksum
2022-02-22T06:30:36.417Z INFO  - f2f4aec225fa Download complete
2022-02-22T06:30:36.498Z INFO  - 5d726bac08ea Downloading 2KB / 2KB
2022-02-22T06:30:36.498Z INFO  - 5d726bac08ea Verifying Checksum
2022-02-22T06:30:36.498Z INFO  - 5d726bac08ea Download complete
2022-02-22T06:30:36.558Z INFO  - 7b0d0cfe99a1 Downloading 1MB / 1MB
2022-02-22T06:30:36.558Z INFO  - 7b0d0cfe99a1 Downloading 1MB / 1MB
2022-02-22T06:30:36.559Z INFO  - 7b0d0cfe99a1 Verifying Checksum
2022-02-22T06:30:36.568Z INFO  - 7b0d0cfe99a1 Download complete
2022-02-22T06:30:36.568Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Downloading 2MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:36.638Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Downloading 3MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:36.748Z INFO  - 2dab00d7d232 Downloading 6MB / 12MB
2022-02-22T06:30:36.840Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Downloading 5MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:36.850Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Downloading 5MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:36.951Z INFO  - 2dab00d7d232 Downloading 10MB / 12MB
2022-02-22T06:30:37.022Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Downloading 7MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:37.050Z INFO  - 2dab00d7d232 Verifying Checksum
2022-02-22T06:30:37.050Z INFO  - 2dab00d7d232 Download complete
2022-02-22T06:30:37.112Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Downloading 9MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:37.223Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Downloading 10MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:37.391Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Downloading 15MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:37.413Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Downloading 11MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:37.785Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Downloading 18MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:37.854Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Verifying Checksum
2022-02-22T06:30:37.855Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Download complete
2022-02-22T06:30:38.624Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Downloading 23MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:38.736Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Downloading 25MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:38.998Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Downloading 29MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:39.197Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Downloading 39MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:39.601Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Downloading 56MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:39.781Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Downloading 60MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:39.961Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Downloading 67MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:40.063Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Downloading 68MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:40.264Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Downloading 74MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:40.788Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Downloading 95MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:40.897Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Downloading 98MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:41.006Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Verifying Checksum
2022-02-22T06:30:41.007Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Download complete
2022-02-22T06:30:42.236Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 1MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:42.378Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 1MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:42.468Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 2MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:43.269Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 4MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:43.641Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 5MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:44.022Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 6MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:44.232Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 6MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:44.476Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 7MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:44.766Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 8MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:44.876Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 9MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:45.009Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 9MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:45.278Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 11MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:45.389Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 12MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:45.512Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 13MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:45.732Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 15MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:46.106Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 16MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:46.446Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 19MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:46.547Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 20MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:46.787Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 22MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:47.441Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 24MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:48.377Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 25MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:48.808Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Extracting 25MB / 25MB
2022-02-22T06:30:49.560Z INFO  - 6552179c3509 Pull complete
2022-02-22T06:30:49.626Z INFO  - d69aa66e4482 Extracting 1KB / 1KB
2022-02-22T06:30:49.627Z INFO  - d69aa66e4482 Extracting 1KB / 1KB
2022-02-22T06:30:50.073Z INFO  - d69aa66e4482 Pull complete
2022-02-22T06:30:50.354Z INFO  - 3b19465b002b Extracting 256KB / 3MB
2022-02-22T06:30:50.556Z INFO  - 3b19465b002b Extracting 2MB / 3MB
2022-02-22T06:30:50.808Z INFO  - 3b19465b002b Extracting 3MB / 3MB
2022-02-22T06:30:50.826Z INFO  - 3b19465b002b Extracting 3MB / 3MB
2022-02-22T06:30:50.989Z INFO  - 3b19465b002b Pull complete
2022-02-22T06:30:51.033Z INFO  - 7b0d0cfe99a1 Extracting 32KB / 1MB
2022-02-22T06:30:51.275Z INFO  - 7b0d0cfe99a1 Extracting 256KB / 1MB
2022-02-22T06:30:51.382Z INFO  - 7b0d0cfe99a1 Extracting 1MB / 1MB
2022-02-22T06:30:51.445Z INFO  - 7b0d0cfe99a1 Extracting 1MB / 1MB
2022-02-22T06:30:51.572Z INFO  - 7b0d0cfe99a1 Pull complete
2022-02-22T06:30:51.627Z INFO  - 9ccd5a5c8987 Extracting 149B / 149B
2022-02-22T06:30:51.628Z INFO  - 9ccd5a5c8987 Extracting 149B / 149B
2022-02-22T06:30:51.916Z INFO  - 9ccd5a5c8987 Pull complete
2022-02-22T06:30:52.202Z INFO  - 2dab00d7d232 Extracting 320KB / 12MB
2022-02-22T06:30:52.302Z INFO  - 2dab00d7d232 Extracting 1MB / 12MB
2022-02-22T06:30:52.514Z INFO  - 2dab00d7d232 Extracting 3MB / 12MB
2022-02-22T06:30:52.779Z INFO  - 2dab00d7d232 Extracting 4MB / 12MB
2022-02-22T06:30:53.009Z INFO  - 2dab00d7d232 Extracting 5MB / 12MB
2022-02-22T06:30:53.139Z INFO  - 2dab00d7d232 Extracting 5MB / 12MB
2022-02-22T06:30:53.593Z INFO  - 2dab00d7d232 Extracting 7MB / 12MB
2022-02-22T06:30:54.187Z INFO  - 2dab00d7d232 Extracting 9MB / 12MB
2022-02-22T06:30:54.578Z INFO  - 2dab00d7d232 Extracting 10MB / 12MB
2022-02-22T06:30:54.679Z INFO  - 2dab00d7d232 Extracting 10MB / 12MB
2022-02-22T06:30:55.040Z INFO  - 2dab00d7d232 Extracting 11MB / 12MB
2022-02-22T06:30:55.423Z INFO  - 2dab00d7d232 Extracting 12MB / 12MB
2022-02-22T06:30:55.603Z INFO  - 2dab00d7d232 Extracting 12MB / 12MB
2022-02-22T06:30:57.706Z INFO  - 2dab00d7d232 Pull complete
2022-02-22T06:30:57.758Z INFO  - 5d726bac08ea Extracting 2KB / 2KB
2022-02-22T06:30:57.759Z INFO  - 5d726bac08ea Extracting 2KB / 2KB
2022-02-22T06:30:58.065Z INFO  - 5d726bac08ea Pull complete
2022-02-22T06:30:58.122Z INFO  - f2f4aec225fa Extracting 252B / 252B
2022-02-22T06:30:58.123Z INFO  - f2f4aec225fa Extracting 252B / 252B
2022-02-22T06:30:58.413Z INFO  - f2f4aec225fa Pull complete
2022-02-22T06:30:58.718Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 544KB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:58.961Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 2MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:59.202Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 4MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:59.461Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 6MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:59.712Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 9MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:30:59.974Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 10MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:00.227Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 12MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:00.457Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 14MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:00.556Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 15MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:01.520Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 17MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:01.763Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 19MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:02.453Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 22MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:02.771Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 24MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:03.054Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 27MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:03.324Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 29MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:03.574Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 31MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:03.827Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 33MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:04.085Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 35MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:04.361Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 37MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:04.612Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 39MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:04.912Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 41MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:05.165Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 44MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:05.486Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 45MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:05.759Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 47MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:06.121Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 49MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:06.319Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 50MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:06.612Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 52MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:06.884Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 54MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:07.601Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 56MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:07.843Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 58MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:08.096Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 61MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:08.476Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 64MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:08.928Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 68MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:09.190Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 70MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:09.443Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 73MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:09.673Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 74MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:09.944Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 77MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:10.577Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 79MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:10.840Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 81MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:11.102Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 83MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:11.352Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 85MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:12.044Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 87MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:12.283Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 89MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:12.604Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 91MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:13.086Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 94MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:13.408Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 96MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:13.771Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 98MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:14.405Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 99MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:14.525Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 100MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:15.058Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 102MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:15.961Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 102MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:17.521Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Extracting 103MB / 103MB
2022-02-22T06:31:17.996Z INFO  - 28a8d7e9eac1 Pull complete
2022-02-22T06:31:18.317Z INFO  - 96d7660d55cf Extracting 4KB / 4KB
2022-02-22T06:31:18.329Z INFO  - 96d7660d55cf Extracting 4KB / 4KB
2022-02-22T06:31:19.208Z INFO  - 96d7660d55cf Pull complete
2022-02-22T06:31:19.275Z INFO  - c4976e34a8d2 Extracting 121B / 121B
2022-02-22T06:31:19.276Z INFO  - c4976e34a8d2 Extracting 121B / 121B
2022-02-22T06:31:19.798Z INFO  - c4976e34a8d2 Pull complete
2022-02-22T06:31:19.902Z INFO  -  Digest: sha256:6c75a3ede385188dca74670e94c92ce11a0307a0ad4448265afe0d3c815dfe48
2022-02-22T06:31:19.959Z INFO  -  Status: Downloaded newer image for mysql:5.7
2022-02-22T06:31:19.965Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 45 Seconds
2022-02-22T06:31:20.027Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2022-02-22T06:31:20.027Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 0:3306 --name learn-docker-app_db_0_50d00a16 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=learn-docker-app -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=learn-docker-app.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=7d84ad198c6f807fbfa2076d1e286d2bb239ec2b3ab1f48a5008aac89bd50ca3 mysql:5.7  

2022-02-22T06:31:20.027Z INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
```

Docker-compose.yml file contains:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data:
```

I would appreciate any pointer to what I might be doing wrong.

P.S: it is a linux web-app

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, this is not supported to open SSH on the multi-container web app.

Looks like there is already a [feedback request](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/search/?q=support-ssh-to-specific-container-in-multi-contain) is open on the same, We would suggest you to make comment & upvote it as well.

If you want to [enable/Open an SSH Session to a Linux container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-linux-open-ssh-session) you refer to this documentation.

For more information, you can refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57676203/how-to-ssh-in-to-different-containers-in-multi-container-azure-app-service) thread.

Comment: Thank you @VenkateshDodda-MT. According to the documentation, I should be able ot access the public-facing image - in my case WordPress, over the SSH option in the app service blade. But I still get that error. Kindly advice. I added my docker-compose.yml file to edit